# Why does plotly express give me an attribute error when I make a line chart?

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to use plotly to build a line chart. Here is the code I wrote:

```
from fredapi import Fred
import plotly.express as px
fred = Fred("1c242ee90989c94ffb93c923d94e855f")
tran = pd.DataFrame(fred.get_series("EMISSCO2TOTVTCTOUSA"))
tran.columns = ["CO2"]
tran = tran.reset_index()
fig = px.line(tran, x = "index", y = "CO2")
fig.show()
```

Why do I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'layout'

Comment: Please post the _full_ error message

Comment: I can produce a line chart from your code. What version of Plotly are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Using the [latest version](https://pypi.org/project/plotly/) of Plotly (version 5.4.0 at the time of posting), I can produce a line chart from your code.

```
from fredapi import Fred
import plotly.express as px
fred = Fred("1c242ee90989c94ffb93c923d94e855f")
tran = pd.DataFrame(fred.get_series("EMISSCO2TOTVTCTOUSA"))
tran.columns = ["CO2"]
tran = tran.reset_index()
fig = px.line(tran, x = "index", y = "CO2")
fig.show()
```

[image]